# Dynamically change mysql query in php with java (android)

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, dynamic

I'm using a MySQL database and php for my java/android app.
I haven't got any experience with php.

this is my php file (getAllDataFromSomeTable.php)

```
<?php
mysql_connect("someHosturl","someUsername","somePassword");
mysql_select_db("databasename");

$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sometable");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]= $e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

and i work with HttpPosts and stuff like that in Java.
This way i can get all the data from 'sometable'

but if i want to use a different query like "select top 1 from sometable where username = 'thisuser'" for example. How can i change that dynamically in java?
How should my php file look and how should the code in java look?
this is the code i have now:

```
String result = "";
    List<? extends NameValuePair> licenses = (List<? extends NameValuePair>) new ArrayList<DriversLicense>();
    InputStream is = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://some-url.com/getAllDataFromSomeTable.php");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(licenses));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("httpclient tag", e.getMessage());
    }

    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        result=sb.toString();
        Log.d("result is", result);
    }catch(Exception e){
         Log.d("log-tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("from jsonObject", "id= " + json_data.getInt("Id") + ", number = "
                        +json_data.getString("Number"));
        }
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try adding parametes to the request?

For example:

http://some-url.com/getAllDataFromSomeTable.php?table=difftable&whereField.1=username&whereValue.1=xyz&whereField.2=surname&whereValue.2=Smith

This way you would need to parse these parameters and build a query based on the passed data.
I'm thinking that the above request would make this query:

```
select * from difftable where username = 'xyz' and surname ='Smith'
```

On the other hand, this is what webservices are for, so i would think about something like that, if possible.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it out, it's probably gonna work that way, but like i said, i have no experience in webservices or php :p tnx for the quick respond. But how should i write the query in the php file? can i put something in there like "$query" and than in java "someurl.com/getda...table.php?query=" + queryString ;

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Then in php, you can get the query parameter of url with:

$_GET['query']

I'm not sure thought about security stuff, if some finds out this URL, then your DB can be easily overloaded or anything.